# Laravel - Implementing Fortify two-factor authentication without Jetstream

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I'm struggling to figure out how to implement 2FA provided by Laravel/Fortify (https://github.com/laravel/fortify) without using Jetstream. Currently there is no documentation regarding how to do it.

I have the `twoFactorAuthenication` enabled in the **`config/fortify.php`**

```
'features' => [
    // Features::registration(),
    // Features::resetPasswords(),
    // Features::emailVerification(),
    // Features::updateProfileInformation(),
    Features::updatePasswords(),
    Features::twoFactorAuthentication([
        'confirmPassword' => true,
    ]),
],
```

I have registered the `twoFactorChallengeView` in **`Providers\FortifyServerProvider`**

```
public function boot()
{    
    Fortify::twoFactorChallengeView('auth.two-factor-challenge');
```

And the account I'm testing the login with has values set in the `two_factor_secret` and `two_factor_recovery_code` fields

I have even compared my code to a working app with 2FA (a fresh install of Laravel 8 with Jetstream) but I can't see any difference in the configuration.

I am able to authenticate successfully but the 2FA challenge is never triggered.

What have I missed?

Comment: What is not working for you? I reckon you did publish the fortify assets. Are the routes now available?

Comment: I can't get the 2FA to trigger. If I navigate to the  `/two-factor-challenge` route manually, it instantly redirects me. So the route is registered but the logic isn't working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the file App\Models\User.php

```
use Laravel\Fortify\TwoFactorAuthenticatable;
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use TwoFactorAuthenticatable;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I missed. They really should release some proper documentation...

Comment: Well that doesn't work for me. Fresh install with breeze and fortify but  without challenge two factor, just login.

Comment: @user1721620 you found any solution?

Comment: No, there is no any solution for this. So i make 2step with email instead of APP